# How can we get the table count with specific date when rows adding day to day in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Hi all please help me to get the result on date wise selection

For example I have table and rows on 14-08-2022

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

and rows added on 15-08-2022

```
id name
4   D
5   E
```

and rows added  on 16-08-2022

```
id name
6   F
7   G
```

If I select date 14-08-2022 i should get result

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

If I select date 14-08-2022 to 15-08-2022 i should get result

```
id name
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D
5   E
```

If I select date 15-08-2022 to 16-08-2022 i should get result

```
id name
4   D
5   E
6   F
7   G
```

Please let me know the query in sql

Comment: Please consider following [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: If the column which stores the datetime when the row was inserted then use this column in WHERE. Otherwise the task is unsolvable.

Comment: What is the name of the column that stores the date?

Comment: @J.D. I don't have Date Column

Comment: Are you able to modify the table that holds the data at all and add new columns?

Comment: "*I don't have Date Column*" - Then as Akina mentioned, it's not possible to solve your problem. You should add a date column to the table.

Comment: Rows don't magically have an InsertedAt column. You should add one: `ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD InsertedAt datetime2 DEFAULT SYSDATETIME()` but this won't fix old data